# MYSQL Truncate resulting in Wrong Calculations

Tags: mysql, sql-update

When I run below:

balance = TRUNCATE(19.91 + 0.08, 2)

In an update operations into a mysql db, I get 19.98 as the result instead of 19.99.

What could be causing this and how do i resolve it?

I have tried to remove the TRUNCATE operation and i get the right result and when i just enter 19.99 i get the right result.

Comment: does it work with TRUNCATE(19.91 + 0.08, 3)

Comment: you can use `round(...)` (have a look at https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: Always specify the exact version of the server in the question

Comment: Looks good to me https://dbfiddle.uk/DJrPpRm2 please add the definition for balance , the mysql version and enough sample data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I believe the error is from getting 19.98999999 due to some precision setting and truncate just cuts off the rest